# I want to access an array specified by a tableview in another class

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

As shown I tried to redeclare the array outside of the tableview function.  I have also tried calling up `ViewController.tableView()` from the class I want the array to be in.  I think what I need to know is how do I get the array out of the tableview into anything else.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ("BasicCell")

    let keyTitle = keys[indexPath.row].keyTitle
    let keyItself = keys[indexPath.row].keyItself

    var keyArray = []
    keyArray = keyItself

    cell.textLabel?.text = keyTitle

    return cell
}

var theKey: Array = keyItself
```

Comment: i did not understand how functions worked. i finally learned of my stupidity. you can have functions pull in data which would have solved my problems. I didnt understand that i did not have a view comtroller class but a separate class. Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewController` does refer to the class while `theKey` property does belong to the instance of the class `ViewController`.

So to access your array you'll need a reference to the class of ViewController.

Something like this

```
let viewController: ViewController = ... // get your instance somehow
viewController.tableView()
```

Answer (score 0):

I implore you, don't go down that path! I have seen it many times before and it has practically always ended in disaster.

A view controller is there to manage a view and react to the interaction of user input by informing a data model, and to manage changes of the data model and display them to the user. It is **not** there to store an array.

If you need data that is shared by more than one view controller, there are several options. The ugliest and perhaps easiest is to give your `AppDelegate` an array property that can hold this data.

*Even the mere enumeration of the other options would go beyond the scope of this question.*

Comment: mundi i see what you mean, but im just a begginer so could you please elaborate on how to give properties to app delegate?

Comment: Just declare a `var` inside your `AppDelegate` class.

Comment: ok but the table view determines which array i use depending on which row is clicked.  How do i take the data determined by the table view and give it to a separate class? thanks for all of your help!

Comment: You usually do this in `prepareForSegue`. There you can pass the object to the segue's destination controller for filtering.

Comment: ok i watched some videos and mostly understand this segue code I came up with but there is a few problems I will list below

Comment: override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboard, sender: AnyObject?) {
            var DestViewController : Decisions = segue.destinationViewController as! Decisions
            DestViewController.keyArray = keyArray1 as! [String]
        }

Comment: Xcode doesn't like the "override" part not being in a class but I'm not sure how "activate" this code because in my prior experiments I learned that I could not call upon functions in the tableview.  It also says the UIStoryboard has no member destinationViewController.

Comment: oh and i almost forgot.  keyArray is an array in the class Decisions which I am trying to store the data in